# RSpec ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find User with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, devise

There are many answered questions about this topic but I can't seem to apply the answers to my issue. I'm getting the following error:

```
ItemsController POST create redirect to show page
     Failure/Error: @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

I know the reason for the error is because the user_id is nil but I can't seem to figure out the reason why. I'm still fairly new to Rails so excuse me if this is a really easy fix.

**RSpec Test**

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe ItemsController, type: :controller do

  describe "POST create" do
    it "redirect to show page" do
      post :create, user_id: @user, item: { name: "name"}
      expect(response).to redirect_to(user_show_path)
    end
  end
end
```

**Items Controller**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.user = current_user
    if @item.save
      @item = Item.update_items(params[:items])
      redirect_to current_user, notice: "Item was saved successfully."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating item. Please try again."
      render user_show_path
    end
  end


  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
user_items POST   /users/:user_id/items(.:format)   items#create
```

...and I've implemented **Devise** for the user part. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Try `post :create, user_id: @user.id, item: { name: "name"}`

Comment: I tried that and the errors turns into: NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You didn't define @user in your test.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create @user before using it. You can use factory_girl gem or directly do

```
 @user = User.create
 post :create, user_id: @user.id, item: { name: "name"}
```

Hope this works

Comment: Thank you for your help!